# Python Classes and Objects to calculate second minimum electricity bill

Tags: python-3.x

Create a class called apartment with attributes flatnumber,owner name,electricity bill 
amount.Create another class apartment_demo with def init(self):pass to create a method 
getSecondMinBill that takes the list of objects and gives the second minimum electricity 
bill as output.

```
Input:3(no.of objects to be created)
1000
Hari
5000
1001
Hena
5002
1002
Harsha
5001
Output:5001
```

This is what I'm trying to do but stuck what to do further on:

```
    class apartment:
        flatnumber=int()
        owner_name=str()
        ele_bill_amount=int()

    class apartment_demo:
        def __init__(self):
            pass
        def get_second_minimum():
            #Help
    list=[]
    a=int(input())
    for i in range(a):
        #How to call get_second_minimum ?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class apartment:
    def __init__(self,fn,on,eb):
        self.fn=fn
        self.on=on
        self.eb=eb

class apartment_demo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def calculate(self,l):
        a=[]
        for i in l:
            a.append(i.eb)
        a.sort()
        return a[1] 
if __name__=='__main__':
    l=[]
    count=int(input())
    for i in range(count):
        fn=int(input())
        on=input()
        eb=int(input())
        l.append(apartment(fn,on,eb))
    t=apartment_demo()
    s=t.calculate(l)
    print(s)
```

Thanks to me.